# Angular: is it possible to use optional useClass in provides, in my case only load GlobalErrorHandler when not in dev mode

Tags: angular

So I got this code which works great to handle errors, only that I only want to load it when I am not developing, is it possible to set a load condition for `useClass` in providers:

```
providers: [
        {
            provide: ErrorHandler, // if in dev mode don't load this
            useClass: GlobalErrorHandler
        }
```

thanks

Sean

Answer (score 0):

Setup **[Environments](https://balramchavan.medium.com/configure-and-build-angular-application-for-different-environments-7e94a3c0af23)**, and export an environment variable in case of **dev** environment. (empty object in case of production / staging environment)

Comment: but how do you code the optional return class value?

Answer (score 0):

```
export function provideGlobalErrorHandler() {
    if (Lib.DevMode()) {
        return {
            provide: ErrorHandler,
            useClass: GlobalErrorHandler
        };
    }
}
```